# Getting error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'

Tags: sql, vb.net

I seem to keep getting the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'." when trying to grab a column from one table and put it into another. I've created the following SQL Script for it:

```
STUFF (ISNULL( (SELECT 
                      (SELECT '§§ ' + CONTEXT
                      FROM NOTES P2
                      WHERE P2.CustomerID = P1.CustomerID
                      ORDER BY Customerid
                      FOR XML PATH('') )
                      FROM NOTES p1 WHERE CUSTOMERID IN (CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID)
                      GROUP BY Customerid 
                      ),'')  ,1, 1, '') DriverNotes
```

And in VB.NET I have the following example:

```
info.EmergencyContact = .GetString(31)
info.EmergencyContactPhone = .GetString(32)
info.DriverNotes = .GetString(33)
```

I only get the error when `info.DriverNotes = .GetString(33)` is present, otherwise everything works fine without it. I have tried multiple things which include using `CAST` and `CONVERT` in SQL but no luck there.

Comment: What is the type of `DriverNotes` column?

Comment: The type would be nchar.

Comment: If the data is not a `String` then why you be surprised that `GetString` wouldn't work? If it's an `Int64`, call `GetInt64`.  If you want a `String`, call `ToString` on that `Int64`.

Comment: I have tried that, but my column only returns the value "33" for every record.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your SQL.  You are getting the data that your SQL generates.  If that's not the dat you want then your SQL is wrong.  Fix your SQL.  Get it right in the database first, then you can transfer it to your VB application.

Comment: When you run the query on the database, is column 34 the DriverNotes column?

Comment: Note that `.GetString(int i)` is zero-based, so `GetString(0)` retrieves the first column and `GetString(33)`retrieves the 34th column.

Comment: jmcilhinney: I will look into that, I figured my SQL was correct since it works when info.drivernotes is missing from VB. Stijin, I just noticed that and it is column 34. Going to make some changes there and see what happens. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: So I tried making some changes with the columns, I get the same error but this time with system.int32 instead of systems.int64. Also, why the downvote? I don't understand why some people react so negatively here at times when the site is clearly trying to provide help to others. I am still green to programming with a lot to learn, no need to chastise me for it.

Comment: This is strictly a debugging issue.  Presumably `.GetString(33)` is being called on a datareader instance and the field at index 33 is not a string type.  You can use something like `Dim colIndex As Int32 = 33 : Dim fieldInfo As String = $"Field Name: {rdr.GetName(colIndex)}, DB Type Name: {rdr.GetDataTypeName(colIndex)}, System Type: {rdr.GetFieldType(colIndex)}"` to investigate this. In this example, `rdr` is a datareader.

Comment: Thank you for the reply TnTinMn, I'll try that out as well. Still having that same issue, just had to shelve it for a minute.